# windows c++ change windows DNS server with SetInterfaceDnsSettings/GetInterfaceDnsSettings?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I'm looking for a way to change DNS using C++.

The official document I came across is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-setinterfacednssettings

But it gives no examples.

The other method I found is

1. change registry
   [C++ Add DNS entry into network adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703053/c-add-dns-entry-into-network-adapter)

   Not what I need.
2. C# example [How do I change/set DNS with c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078570/how-do-i-change-set-dns-with-c)

   Funy, there is even a C# example, but no c++.
3. This method kinda execute some system commands I guess, https://github.com/w123l123h/netConfig

   Not what I want neither.

I know I can easily achieve the goal by calling `netsh` command.

But, is there some workable examples for `SetInterfaceDnsSettings/GetInterfaceDnsSettings`

This is my sample code, the returned ret value is always 87, NameServer is NULl.

The interfaceGUID is got from GetAdaptersInfo() api.

```
void get_dns()
{
     GUID interfaceGUID = {0xFD113810, 0x2F5A, 0x4947, {0xA1, 0x19, 0xA5, 0xC9, 0x74, 0x15, 0x88, 0x26}};

     DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS *settings;
     DWORD ret = GetInterfaceDnsSettings(interfaceGUID, settings);
     printf("result: %lu\n", ret);
     printf("NameServer: %ls\n", settings->NameServer);
}
```

Follow up question.

SetInterfaceDnsSettings() does not work.

This my code.

```
GUID interfaceGUID;
    LPCOLESTR lpsz = L"{1CA18531-B5FA-4A92-837A-AE12298FFF7F}";
    HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString(lpsz, &interfaceGUID);
    if (hr != S_OK)
    {
        printf("get guid error!!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS settings = { DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS_VERSION1 };
    settings.NameServer = L"8.8.8.8";
    printf("NameServer: %ls\n", settings.NameServer);

    DWORD ret = SetInterfaceDnsSettings(interfaceGUID, &settings);
    printf("result: %lu\n", ret);
```

The ret value returned is 0, I guess it means no error.

But it did not change the DNS of the interface. Whether it's got from GetInterfaceDnsSettings or Control Panel.

Comment: I never used this API, but I would imagine that there's nothing more to it than `Get`ting the respective settings, making modifications, and `Set`ting them back. What's the specific issue you're having?

Comment: I add my non-working sample code to the question.

Comment: Passing an uninitialized pointer value isn't going to have well-defined behavior.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to init it, and there is no document about it.

Comment: `DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS settings = { DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS_VERSION1 }; GetInterfaceDnsSettings(interfaceGUID, &settings);`

Comment: @IInspectable
 GetInterfaceDnsSettings() works, But SetInterfaceDnsSettings() doesn't.

Comment: The latter likely requires privileges that a regular user account doesn't hold. Try running the code under an administrative account.

Comment: Just noticed the update to the question. There's a bug in populating the structure. When calling `SetInterfaceDnsSettings` you will have to provide `Flags` that describe the settings that hold valid data/need to be updated. In this case `Flags` needs to have the `DNS_SETTING_NAMESERVER` bit set.

Comment: what should I say, once again, you saved me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @IInspectable's comments, I summarize this question.

`DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS` needs to be properly initialized. When using `SetInterfaceDnsSettings`, you need to declare Flags that you need to modify property in the [DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/ns-netioapi-dns_interface_settings#members).

```
DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS settings;
settings.Version = DNS_INTERFACE_SETTINGS_VERSION1;
settings.Flags = DNS_SETTING_NAMESERVER ;
settings.NameServer = L"8.8.8.8";

DWORD ret = SetInterfaceDnsSettings(interfaceGUID, &settings);
printf("result: %lu\n", ret);
```